# Get Lua to print(functionname.variable)

Tags: function, lua

I am trying to get this to work but I am not sure if Lua supports this kind of variables

```
function newUser(accountName, password)
    accountName = accountName
    password = password
end

testUser = newUser("testName" , "testPassword")

print(testUser.password)
```

Does the `testUser.password` work with Lua?

Comment: Why are you trying JS-style initializers in Lua?

Answer (score 5):

`newUser` is a function, so `testUser` gets the function's return value, that is, nothing. A simple and direct way to fix the problem is to return a table:

```
function newUser(accountName, password)
    local t = {}
    t.accountName = accountName
    t.password = password
    return t
end
```

**EDIT**: Or better, following your style as @lhf suggested:

```
function newUser(accountName, password) 
    return { accountName = accountName, password = password } 
end
```

Comment: In the style of the OP this may be written as `function newUser(accountName, password) return { accountName = accountName,     password = password } end`.